# viewWillAppear called after cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

One of my `UIViewController` with `UICollectionView` crashes sometime when I swipe very fast. It **crashes** in `let option = self.options[indexPath.row]`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell= collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("optionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell

    let option = self.options[indexPath.row]            
    return cell        
}
```

I found the problem is that the `self.options` is not created successfully sometime. I create the `self.options` in `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.options = ...
}
```

There are two possibilities:

1. The `viewWillAppear` is not called at all
2. The `viewWillAppear` will be called after `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Did I miss anything in my code? Thanks

Comment: super.viewWillAppear(true)

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati No, that's not right.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Because if `animated` is `false` then you should pass `false` to `super`.

Comment: call [super viewWillAppear:YES/NO] at first and put your own thing below that.

Comment: I suggest you create self.options in viewdidAppear. Let me know if it works

Comment: @Abdul Yasin,no, it's not working and it's worse. Because the app crashes more frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me the answer lies in another method for your data source: the number of items you have to present.

I would guess the value you are returning in that data source method is not based on the options array and instead hard coded. That would explain why you are being asked to provide a cell for data you don't have set up yet.

Comment: Yes. The *numberOfItemsInSection* will return number of another array. But the count of that array is used to create my options array.

Comment: Why don't you use MIN(options.count, otherArray.count) to be sure you always will have the data you need?

Comment: Just be sure to call reload data on the collectionView after you change your options array or else you might not see any rows!

Comment: Yes.Calling reloadData in viewWillAppear seems solve the problem. But I don't know why the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath still be called when there is no reloadData in my code at all.

Answer (score 1):

In a default implementation, `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will get called after `viewWillAppear:`.

However, `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is initially triggered by a call to `[UICollectionView -layoutSubviews]`. You may be doing something else to make this method get called, which explains the behavior you're seeing. If you want, you can set a breakpoint in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, and look at the stack trace to see why it's being called.

Answer (score 0):

I would work under the assumption that everything needed must be present after viewDidLoad.

For your options array, the safest solution is a getter that calculates the options array when it is not available yet. And of course the count should be taken from the options array, not from another array.